# Importing a Node module into a Sinatra app

Tags: javascript, import, sinatra, node-modules

I have a minimal Sinatra app for testing out the [Britecharts](https://britecharts.github.io/britecharts/index.html) data visualization library (installed as a Node module) locally. I'm having trouble accessing the library files in my Sinatra views.

My `public/js/chart.js` has the following import:

```
import bar from './britecharts/node_modules/britecharts/dist/umd/bar.min.js';
```

The path to the file is valid (I can access it if I paste the path into the browser address bar). However in the dev console I get an error saying:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default

I then put brackets around the variable, as explained in [this guide](https://mattlag.medium.com/es6-modules-getting-started-gotchas-2ad154f38e2e):

```
import { bar } from './britecharts/node_modules/britecharts/dist/umd/bar.min.js';
```

But then I get this error instead:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: bar

Thanks for the help.

[EDIT 04.01.2022]: I've created a GitHub repo for the app:

https://github.com/fullstackplus/britecharts-demo

Comment: What does your `script` tag look like? Is it using `type=module`?

Comment: @BobNadler Yes! `<script type="module" src="js/chart.js"></script>`

Comment: @BobNadler https://github.com/fullstackplus/britecharts-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unpack the Britecharts library files plus dependencies
2. Put them in a folder local to your app
3. Import them in your HTML as below:

```
    <div class="bar-container"></div>
    <script src="/js/britecharts/node_modules/britecharts/dist/umd/bar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/britecharts/node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/chart.js"></script>
```